# How to install app on external sdcard programmatically?

Tags: android, package-managers, android-install-apk, android-external-storage

I´m currently developing an app which works as an Update Manager. So far the app has work great whenever I installed or updated any other app. All these apps have been installed on the data/app folder and I have used the  android.content.pm.IPackageManager class with the installpackage() method to install them.

Im working on a costum ROM which has a Internal Memory (1 GB), a internal SDCARD (4GB), and the External SD CARD (8GB). Due to the fact that all my apps have been installed on the  data/app folder I´m running out of space in my internal memory!. I was wondering if i could use the same installpackage() method to install the apps on the external SDCARD (or the internal).

Here is how i install the apps :

```
 private Class<?> iPackageManagerStubProxyClass;

  iPackageManagerStubProxyClass = Class
 .forName("android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy");



  public void installPackage(Uri uri) throws NoSuchMethodException,
  NumberFormatException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException,
  InvocationTargetException, ClassNotFoundException {
  Log.i(LOG_TAG, "installing without deleting");
  Method method = getMethod(iPackageManagerStubProxyClass, "installPackage");
  method.invoke(packageManagerServiceProxy, uri, getPackageInstallObserver(),
  Integer.valueOf(INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING | INSTALL_INTERNAL), "");
  System.out.println(method);
  }
```

Im starting to suspect that i can´t do the same to install the aplications on the sdcard. Any sugestions? If not ,could I move my apps programatically to the sdcard after instalation?

Comment: Sorry forgot to say that : INSTALL_REPLACE_EXISTING = 0x00000002; INSTALL_INTERNAL = 0x00000010;

Answer (score 5):

Use this code

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:installLocation="preferExternal"
        ... >
```

Comment: after using this i am still not able to see my app folder in my phone disk

Comment: after giving android:installLocation="preferExternal" the app will be installed in your external memory, ie SD Card, check your folder in external memory.

Answer (score 3):

> How to install app on external sdcard programmatically?

**There is no way to do this programatically!** (until now Android 7.0)

you must define inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file the property [`android:installLocation`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

specifying one of this values:

> **"internalOnly"**    The application must be installed on the internal
>   device storage only. If this is set, the application will never be
>   installed on the external storage. If the internal storage is full,
>   then the system will not install the application. This is also the
>   default behavior if you do not define android:installLocation.
>
> **"auto"**    The application may be installed on the external storage, but
>   the system will install the application on the internal storage by
>   default. If the internal storage is full, then the system will install
>   it on the external storage. Once installed, the user can move the
>   application to either internal or external storage through the system
>   settings.
>
> **"preferExternal"**  The application prefers to be installed on the
>   external storage (SD card). There is no guarantee that the system will
>   honor this request. The application might be installed on internal
>   storage if the external media is unavailable or full. Once installed,
>   the user can move the application to either internal or external
>   storage through the system settings.

more [**information**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/install-location.html).